# Invalid CRC32 Hash Generation

Tags: hash, sha1, crypto++, crc32

I'm creating **SHA1** and **CRC32** hash from plain text using Crypto++ Library as the following:

```cxx
#include <cryptopp/filters.h>
#include <cryptopp/hex.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/crc.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Calculate SHA1

    std::string data = "Hello World";
    std::string base_encoded_string;

    byte sha_hash[CryptoPP::SHA::DIGESTSIZE];
    CryptoPP::SHA().CalculateDigest(sha_hash, (byte*)data.data(), data.size());
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss1( std::string(sha_hash, sha_hash+CryptoPP::SHA::DIGESTSIZE), true,
        new CryptoPP::HexEncoder( new CryptoPP::StringSink( base_encoded_string ) ));

    std::cout << base_encoded_string << std::endl;
    base_encoded_string.clear();

    // Calculate CRC32

    byte crc32_hash[CryptoPP::CRC32::DIGESTSIZE];
    CryptoPP::CRC32().CalculateDigest(crc32_hash, (byte*)data.data(), data.size());
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss2( std::string(crc32_hash, crc32_hash+CryptoPP::CRC32::DIGESTSIZE), true,
        new CryptoPP::HexEncoder( new CryptoPP::StringSink( base_encoded_string ) ));

    std::cout << base_encoded_string << std::endl;
    base_encoded_string.clear();

}
```

The output I get is:

> 0A4D55A8D778E5022FAB701977C5D840BBC486D0
>   56B1174A
>   Press any key to continue . . .

And, out of these I confirmed that CRC32 is incorrect according to various online resources such as this one: http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?text=Hello+World

I have no idea why because I'm creating CRC32 hash by following the same procedure as I followed for SHA1. Is there really different way or am I really doing something wrong in here?

Answer (score 1):

> byte crc32_hash[CryptoPP::CRC32::DIGESTSIZE];

I believe you have a bad endian interaction. Treat the CRC32 value is an integer, not a byte array.

So try this:

```
int32_t crc = (crc32_hash[0] << 0) | (crc32_hash[1] << 8) |
                (crc32_hash[2] << 16) | (crc32_hash[3] << 24);
```

*If* `crc32_hash` is integer aligned, then you can:

```
int32_t crc = ntohl(*(int32_t*)crc32_hash);
```

Or, this might be easier:

```
int32_t crc32_hash;
CryptoPP::CRC32().CalculateDigest(&crc32_hash, (byte*)data.data(), data.size());
```

I might be wrong about `int32_t`, it might be `uint32_t` (I did not look at the standard).